# c++ / Append data on a txt file in a specific way

Tags: c++, text, ofstream

I have a txt file like this:

> 123456
>
> 123456
>
> abcdef
>
> ...

With C++, I would like to open it and add data in the following way

> 123456 new data new data
>
> 123456 new data new data
>
> abcdef new data new data
>
> ...

I already saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855043/append-in-each-line-of-a-txt-file-a-specific-string-using-python) on stackOverflow but it's in Python.

I used this function

```
std::ofstream file_to_save;
file_to_save.open(path, ios::out | ios::app);
```

but it adds the data at the end of the file and not next to each word.

**EDIT:** Actually I add the date continuously in a loop and not everything in one time. That's the difficulty. So I have my file with all the date then inside a loop, I create new data. Let's say "new data" and then I would like to assign this new data (always different) to the file which already exist.

> 123456
>
> 123456
>
> abcdef
>
> ...

I create new data in my loop "new data 1" then want to add to the file like that

> 123456 new data 1
>
> 123456
>
> abcdef
>
> ...

Then Step 2 on my loop, I create "new data 2" then want to add to the file like that

> 123456 new data 1
>
> 123456 new data 2
>
> abcdef
>
> ...

Then Step 3 on my loop, I create "new data 3" then want to add to the file like that

> 123456 new data 1
>
> 123456 new data 2
>
> abcdef new data 3
>
> ...
> and so on, until fill the entire file.

Can someone help me ?

Thank

Comment: What about reading the current line, append data to the line and overwrite the file? You have to read anyway the line, so you can overwrite the file

Comment: You can instead do what your python solution did.  Read the entire file, then write the entire file, appending to each line.

Comment: You mean, read each line, save the first data and overwrite in the file ? I didn't get it well.

Comment: I've replied as an answer @lilouch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store the contents of the existing file in an array
or vector and write it back to the same file.

```
void appendToFile(string sFilename, int nInsertAt, string sDataToInsert)
{
    std::ifstream infile("output.txt");

    string line;
    vector<string> vLines;

    while (std::getline(infile, line))
    {
        vLines.push_back(line);
    }

    infile.close();
    std::ofstream outfile("output.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < vLines.size(); i++)
    {
        char buff[1024];
        if (i == nInsertAt)
        {
            sprintf(buff, "%s %s", vLines[i].c_str(), sDataToInsert.c_str());
            outfile << buff << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            outfile << vLines[i] << endl;
        }

    }

    outfile.close();
}

void test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        char buff[1024];
        sprintf(buff, "new data %d", i);
        appendToFile("output.txt", i, buff);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but didn't work...I mean not what I want. I've edited my question, and I think it's more clear now. thank in Advance

Comment: Perfect, works well ! Thank you so much @Christian - PMP. I got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Read all the file and store your strings in a vector. For each element in a vector, append your new data and then write them in the file, overwriting your file entirely.

Alternatively, you can use the seeking function to read/overwrite your file line by line

Comment: Thank for your answer, but didn't work...I mean not what I want. I've edited my question, and I think it's more clear now. Thank in Advance

Comment: But my answer was exactly what you wanted. When someone write "for each element", it's meant a for-loop.

Comment: I didn't get it in this way. Thank

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways of doing this. The safest is usually to copy each line to a new file, append whatever you need to that line, and continue until the end of the input file.

Then you can just copy the data back from the new file to the old one, or (if you're sure there aren't other links to it) delete the old, and rename the new to the old name.

Alternatively, you can copy from the old file to a temporary file, then process the data as you copy it back to the old file (and finally delete the temporary file).

Reading the data into memory, then overwriting the file with the new data is much more fragile--if you get a crash or power loss in the middle of the operation, your file is likely to be destroyed (i.e., you don't have a copy of either the old *or* the new data. I'd avoid it unless you're really so much more worried about speed than reliability that you don't mind the possibility of destroying the data entirely.

Obvious code:

```
std::ifstream input("filename");
std::ofstream output("filename2");

std::string line;

while (std::getline(input, line))
    output << line << " new data new data new data\n";
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but didn't work...I mean not what I want. I've edited my question, and I think it's more clear now. Thank in Advance

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read in you question, you want:

1. **read line**
2. **add new data to it**
3. **store all updated lines**
4. **overwrite the file with the new lines**

Here is one possible implemenation:

```
ifstream infile("filetobeupdated.txt");
if(!infile) error("Can't open file: ", filetobeupdated);

// vector holding old data
string line;
vector<string>oldlines;

while(getline(infile,line)) oldlines.push_back(line);

infile.close();

// vector holding newdata
vector<string>newdata;

// vector holding updated data
vector<string>updateddata;

// concatenate old line + new data 
for(size_t i=0, i<oldlines.size();i++) updateddata.push_back(oldlines[i]+newdata[i]);                                                     

// overwrite old file with new data
ofstream onfile("filetobeupdated.txt");
if(!onfile) error("Can't open file: ", filetobeupdated);

for(size_t i=0, i<newdata.size();i++) onfile << newdata[i] <<'\n';

onfile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how "ios::app" works--adding data at the end of a file.

You may want to read each line first and then overwrite all the lines.

Comment: Yeah I used it, but in my case, It doesn't work for what i want. See my edit